# Configuration Membership on localhost and real hosting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

On localhost use SQLServer Express Edition. When I upload file to real hosting,my hosting use Full SQL Server 2005. How to config the ConnectionString of Membership(aspnetdb.mdf)

Answer (score 0):

connectionstrings should stay the same. if db and app is same machine and u set location to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

How your ConnectionString for your hosting environment is supposed to look like you should probably find out via the FAQs (or a similar section) on your hoster's page.

On this page you will find a reference of all ConnectionStrings and how to use them:

- [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)